# php xml schema validation alternatives

Tags: php, xml, linux, xsd

The standard validation for XML in PHP is done with DOMDocument::schemaValidate.  This has two problems: error line numbers only work to files up to 65535 lines, and, for large files, the DOM is created first, which has memory limits if the file is large.

What are good alternatives to run on a LINUX machine that will most importantly overcome the memory issue and secondly be able to show the error on lines more than 65535?

Comment: Did you read [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858074/validating-a-large-xml-file-400mb-in-php)?

Comment: schemaValidate requires the path to the schema.  Where in the solution above, do you pass the schema (xsd) file?